# Image shown in PictureBox before captured is different and captured image is different

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using `AForge.video.dll` and `AForge.video.DirectShow.dll`.

I want to save the exact image which is displayed in picturebox at the time of capture (`pbPhoto` is the picturebox I used for displaying the camera video)

```
    void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bit = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pbPhoto.Image = bit;
    }

    private void btImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            photo = true;

            if (!scanFlag)
            {
                btPrintPass.Enabled = false;
                scanFlag = true;                    

                cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(webcam[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
                cam.Start();

                this.btImage.Text = "Stop Scan";
            }
            else
            {
                btPrintPass.Enabled = true;
                scanFlag = false;                    

                if (cam.IsRunning)
                {
                    cam.Stop();
                }               

                this.btImage.Text = "Scan Photo";
                string path = "temp.Jpeg";

                if (pbPhoto.Image != null)
                {
                    pbPhoto.Image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    //this.pictureBox1.Image.Save(path,ImageFormat.Bmp) ;
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                    //long Len = ss.Length ;
                    //this.pictureBox1.Image.Save(
                    m_barrImg = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)];
                    int iBytesRead = fs.Read(m_barrImg, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        { }
    }
```

Comment: How different it is from the image you want? just few frames ahead ?

Comment: picturebox image is shown like zoomed image,but after capturing image it looks like image is captured from too far

Comment: Then i suspect it's the `SizeMode` property of your `picturebox`. What is it set to?

Comment: Sizemode property of picturebox is set to Normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comment, The issue you're facing seems to come from the fact that the `pictuebox.SizeMode` is set to `Normal`.
From MSDN:

> By default, in **Normal mode**, the Image is positioned in the upper-left corner of the PictureBox, and any part of the image that is too big for the PictureBox is clipped.Using the **StretchImage** value causes the image to stretch or shrink to fit the PictureBox. Using the **Zoom** value causes the image to be stretched or shrunk to fit the PictureBox; however, the aspect ratio in the original is maintained.

So if you change the `SizeMode` to `StretchImage` or `Zoom` you will see in the `picturebox` the same exact image.

That said, i would also recommend adding the following checking to your `cam_NewFrame`, since it might be that until the camera actually stops streaming, you will move a few frames ahead.

```
void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (!scanFlag) return;
    Bitmap bit = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    pbPhoto.Image = bit;
}
```